# How to insert data from two form into a table with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two forms and I want to insert data in a table where half of the table contain form1 data and rest of the table contain form2 data. Now it inserts twice in the db table. In first row it inserts form1 and 2nd row it inserts form2. I want them in a one row. How would i do this stuff with jquery.

here is my jquery :

```
    $("#ac_form_submit").click(function() {
      $.post($("#ac_form_1").attr("action"), $("#ac_form_1").serialize(),
       function () {
        alert('Form 1 submitted');
     });

     $.post($("#ac_form_2").attr("action"), $("#ac_form_2").serialize(),
       function () {
        alert('Form 2 submitted');
     });
   })
```

Comment: Wehre is the relation between form 1 and from 2

Comment: how can i set the relation?? there action page is same. Actually i wanted to know how to relate them and insert into one row. 

http://screencast.com/t/QGCTR6Iq

Comment: ok i see an one to one relation. Why you use to Form. Put them together. If you want make fields optional use the hide() function.

Comment: Thanks for reply. ok let me clear you. first, i hide the form2. in form1 when click "next" button it validate form1 (with jquery validator) and then form2 appears. And finally when click "submit" button then it first it validates form2 and then post form1 and form2 into a table row.

Answer (score 1):

NOW it is solved !! :)

```
    $('#ac_form_2').on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form1Data = $('#ac_form_1');
    var form2Data = $('#ac_form_2');
    var action = $("#ac_form_1").attr("action");
    var data = (form1Data.add(form2Data).serialize());
    $.post(action, data, function () {
     alert('Form 1 and 2 submitted');
    });
    return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you use `<fieldsetd>` to separate two parts from the same form.

If you want to submit two different forms to option to send a query string in the POST

```
$("#ac_form_submit").click(function() {
  var ac_form_1 = $("#ac_form_1").serialize();
  var ac_form_2 = $("#ac_form_1").serialize();
  var data = [ac_form_1, ac_form_2].join('&');
  var action = $("#ac_form_1").attr("action");

  $.post(action, data,
   function () {
    alert('Form 1 and 2 submitted');
  });

});
```

In this case `data` is a union of two query strings ie:

```
ac_form_1 = 'a=1&b=2'
ac_form_2 = 'c=3&d=4'
data = 'a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4'
```

Comment: Thanks bro !! Its work fine. But the posted value are blank in field. It just add a new row but not inserting the posted value. Plz need your help !!

Comment: actually i got the problem.. it returns data=[object][object]. now i am trying to convert the object into string.. not succeeded yet. can u help me ?? thanks ..

Comment: I think i am near to the solution. At this stage it shows 

http://screencast.com/t/Z9fWC9Z2

how to fix ?? thanks for helping ..

Comment: are you using serializeArray() ?